formula for $\frac{d}{dp}P_p(A \cap B)$ where A and B are increasing and decreasing respectively in the bond percolation setup
Let A and B be two events that depend on the configuration of a finite set of edges in a bond percolation setup. Suppose A is increasing and B is decreasing. Find a formula for $\frac{d}{dp}P_p(A \cap B)$.
I only know Russo's pivotal formula, can someone give a reference or hint for this?
A is an increasing event if for all $\omega, \omega' \in \Omega, \mathbf{1}_{A}(\omega) \ge \mathbf{1}_{A}(\omega')$ whenever $\omega \ge \omega'.$ Typically $\Omega=\{0,1\}^E,$ where $E$ is the edge set in the setup of Bernoulli percolation.

Perhaps this context is familiar to some users here, but if it's something that can be explained in a few sentences you might find you get a wider audience.  For instance, what does it mean to say that an event is "increasing" or "decreasing"?
